# working directory of running process on mac os

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I want to know the working directory of a process on Mac OS (10.6). I tried finding the PWD environment variable in ps command's output, but the PWD variable is not available there. Is there a better way to find this for a running process on mac?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`lsof -d cwd` will print the current working directories for all of your processes.  If you want to show info on processes you don't own, you need to run it as root (i.e. use `sudo` as a prefix).  If you want to show the info for only certain programs or processes, use e.g. `lsof -a -d cwd -c programname` or `lsof -a -d cwd -p processid` (note: in both cases, the `-a` flag means that the other flags' restrictions get "and"ed together).  `lsof` is pretty complex and has lots more options, so read its man page for more info.

Answer (score 8):

Although [Gordon Davisson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327139/working-directory-of-running-process-on-mac-os) is great, if you want to do it from code without calling out to `lsof`, here's the code you need.  It's inspired by the lsof source and [this blog post](https://astojanov.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/mac-os-x-resolve-absolute-path-using-process-pid/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <libproc.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int ret;
        pid_t pid; 
        char pathbuf[PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE];
        struct proc_vnodepathinfo vpi;

        if (argc > 1) {
                pid = (pid_t) atoi(argv[1]);
                ret = proc_pidpath (pid, pathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf));
                if (ret <= 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: proc_pidpath ();\n", pid);
                        fprintf(stderr, "    %s\n", strerror(errno));
                        return 1;
                }
                printf("proc %d executable: %s\n", pid, pathbuf);
                ret = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDVNODEPATHINFO, 0, &vpi,
                                   sizeof(vpi));
                if (ret <= 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: proc_pidinfo ();\n", pid);
                        fprintf(stderr, "    %s\n", strerror(errno));
                        return 1;
                }
                printf("proc %d cwd: %s\n", pid, vpi.pvi_cdir.vip_path);
                // printf("proc %d root: %s\n", pid, vpi.pvi_rdir.vip_path);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

This sample code will produce output like this:

```
 proc 44586 executable: /bin/zsh
 proc 44586 cwd: /private/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about doing it within a Cocoa program, this will work:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *currentPath = [fm currentDirectoryPath];
```